# Ant isset behaviour

Tags: ant

According to the documentation isset clause "Test whether a given property has been set in this project". I don't understand wheter isset returns true or false when a property is set
In the below code snippet java.pass.home is set to somval when env.JAVA_HOME is not set .

```
<condition property="java.passed.home" value="somval">
    <isset property="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
</condition>
```

This snippet works for my requirement but i think the correct code snippet should be something like this as i want to set the property when another property is not available

```
<condition property="java.passed.home" value="somval">
    <not>
        <isset property="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
```

Can some one please clarify this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, what you're trying would work. `<not>` negates the result of the condition.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is it documented or something that would be helpful to better understand this

Comment: See [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html).

Comment: The definition itself _appears_ to be pretty clear.  `The <not> element expects exactly one other condition to be nested into this element, negating the result of the condition. ...`

Comment: `isset` is a conditional to test whether a given property has been set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code snippet was right but the property should be mentioned with just name without enclosing it with {}

```
<isset property="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
```

It should be

```
<isset property="env.JAVA_HOME"/>
```